# Maximum Multiplication of 3 Numbers Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm still new in Swift programming, currently struggling why in some cases in hackerrank (https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/nano-challenge-2-code-contest/challenges/maximum-multiplication/problem). I always get a runtime error.

The question:

> Given array of integer, find maximum multiplication of 3 numbers element in the array. Let we have [2, 5, 8], then 80 is the maximum number of 3 multiplication of the element in the array. We get 80 from 2 * 5 * 8. The number of elements in the array can be negative.
>
> **Input Format**
>
> First line denotes n as number of array. Second line is element of array
>
> **Constraints**
>
> ```
> 3 < n < 1000
> -1000 < a[i] < 1000
> ```
>
> **Output Format**
>
> integer of maximum value of multiplication of 3 numbers
>
> **Sample Input 0**
>
> ```
> 3
> ```

```
2 5 8
```

> **Sample Output 0**
>
> ```
> 80
> ```
>
> **Sample Input 1**
>
> ```
> 6
> -10 -3 -1 0 4 8
> ```
>
> **Sample Output 1**
>
> ```
> 240
> ```

**My old solution:**

```
func maxMultiplication(arr: [Int]) -> Int {
    var minus = [Int]()
    var plus = [Int]()
    
    var answer = 0
   
    for x in arr {
        if x<0 {
            minus.append(x)
        }
        else {
            plus.append(x)
        }
    }
    
    minus.sort()
    plus.sort()
    
    //let p = plus[plus.count-1] * plus[plus.count-2] * plus[plus.count-3]
    //let m = plus[plus.count-1] * minus[0] * minus[1]
    
    if plus.count==0 {
        let x = minus[minus.count-1] * minus[minus.count-2] * minus[minus.count-3]
        answer = x
    }
    else if minus.count == 0 {
        let p = plus[plus.count-1] * plus[plus.count-2] * plus[plus.count-3]
        answer = p
    }
    else{
        let p = plus[plus.count-1] * plus[plus.count-2] * plus[plus.count-3]
        let m = plus[plus.count-1] * minus[0] * minus[1]
        if p>m {
            answer = p
        }
        else {
            answer = m
        }
    }
    
    return answer

}
```

**My current solution is:**

```
func maxMultiplication(arr: [Int]) -> Int {
    var minus = [Int]()
    var plus = [Int]()
    
    var answer = 0
   
    for x in arr {
        if x<0 {
            minus.append(x)
        }
        else {
            plus.append(x)
        }
    }
    
    minus.sort()
    plus.sort()
    
    //let p = plus[plus.count-1] * plus[plus.count-2] * plus[plus.count-3]
    //let m = plus[plus.count-1] * minus[0] * minus[1]
    
    if plus.count==0 {
        let x = minus[minus.count-1] * minus[minus.count-2] * minus[minus.count-3]
        answer = x
    }
    else if minus.count == 0 {
        let p = plus[plus.count-1] * plus[plus.count-2] * plus[plus.count-3]
        answer = p
    }
    else if plus.count==2 && minus.count == 1{
    answer = plus[0] * plus [1] * minus[0]
    }
    else if plus.count==1 && minus.count == 2{
       answer = plus[0] * minus[1] * minus[0]
    }

    else{
        let p = plus[plus.count-1] * plus[plus.count-2] * plus[plus.count-3]
        let m = plus[plus.count-1] * minus[0] * minus[1]
        if p>m {
            answer = p
        }
        else {
            answer = m
        }
    }
    
    return answer

}
```

**I DID IT! Thank you guys :") can't do it without yall**

Final Solution:

```
func maxMultiplication(arr: [Int]) -> Int {
    var minus = [Int]()
    var plus = [Int]()
    
    var answer = 0
   
    for x in arr {
        if x<0 {
            minus.append(x)
        }
        else {
            plus.append(x)
        }
    }
    
    minus.sort()
    plus.sort()
    
    //let p = plus[plus.count-1] * plus[plus.count-2] * plus[plus.count-3]
    //let m = plus[plus.count-1] * minus[0] * minus[1]
    
    if plus.count==0 {
        let x = minus[minus.count-1] * minus[minus.count-2] * minus[minus.count-3]
        answer = x
    }
    else if minus.count == 0 {
        let p = plus[plus.count-1] * plus[plus.count-2] * plus[plus.count-3]
        answer = p
    }
    else if plus.count==2 && minus.count == 1{
    answer = plus[0] * plus [1] * minus[0]
    }
    else if plus.count==1 && minus.count == 2{
       answer = plus[0] * minus[1] * minus[0]
    }
     else if plus.count==1 && minus.count>=3 {
    let a = plus[plus.count-1] * minus[1] * minus[0]
    let b = minus[2] * minus[1] * minus[0]
    if a>b {
           answer = a
       }
       else {
           answer = b
       }
 }
else if plus.count>=3 && minus.count==1 {
    let a = plus[plus.count-1] * plus[plus.count-2] * plus[plus.count-3]
    let b = plus[plus.count-1] * plus[plus.count-2] * minus[0]
    
    if a>b {
        answer = a
    }
    else {
        answer = b
    }
}

    else{
        let p = plus[plus.count-1] * plus[plus.count-2] * plus[plus.count-3]
        let m = plus[plus.count-1] * minus[0] * minus[1]
        if p>m {
            answer = p
        }
        else {
            answer = m
        }
    }
    
    return answer

}
```

- edit: Just one more one-time error, still trying to figure out what's the error

Comment: Can you confirm that this challenge is now closed? Posting solutions to online contests undermines it for everyone.

Comment: Also, your Input 0 is incorrectly formatted. It should be two lines according to the instructions (the 3 should almost certainly be on its own line, which explains why the result appears incorrect).

Comment: It's a close competition for my academy that has ended today, so it's okay to post the solution

Comment: @FelixMarianayagam woops, i made a mistake in the post, already corrected

Comment: Hint: `[-1, 2, 3]` crashes.  Find out why.

Comment: What is the issue with your code, I can not see any question being asked here? Also see [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: What is the logic for negative numbers? For example: In input -10 -3 -1 0 4 8, -10 is the least and 8 is the largest, therefore, the max three numbers should be 8 * 4 * -1. Which will result in 32. Is that right?

Comment: @FelixMarianayagam It will be -10*-10*-8, the logic is to find the highest value of 3 numbers multiplication

Comment: In that case, the result should be 800 and not 240 like you have specified in your question.

Comment: @vacawama Thank you! Just corrected for 2 positive, 1 minus value and 2 minus with 1 positive value, but i still got one runtime error, i will try to recheck my code

Comment: @FelixMarianayagam in sample input 1 which is -10 -3 -1 0 4 8,  the correct answer is -10* -3 * 8 = 240. there is only one -10

Comment: Why do you select -10 * -3 * 8? Why did you leave 4? Shouldn't it be -10 * 4 * 8 = 320

Comment: @FelixMarianayagam -10*4*8 = -320 not 320, 240 is higher than -320.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  When you update your question, add to it but don't take things away.  If someone had posted an answer to your original version, that answer would now be invalid because your code has changed.  Instead, leave the original code there and post your latest below that.

Comment: If that's the case, -1 * 4 * 8 = -32, which is higher than -240

Comment: @vacawama oh thank you, wont do the same in the future. sorry still newbie here hehehe

Comment: @FelixMarianayagam no, -10* -3 * 8 = 240 is higher than -1*4*8, so the focus is to find the highest positive value, or if all the answer is negative, closest to zero is better

Comment: Hint: `[-1,2,3,4]` and `[1,-2,-3,-4]` still crash. Think about the assumptions your `else` is making.

Comment: @vacawama ah, I see the problem but still can't find a solution to it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put together a quick version of the code. Didn't have time to optimize it. I'll leave that to you. Hope this helps.

Tested with the below inputs.

```
values = [-10,-3,-1,0,4,8]
print(findMaxMultiplicationOf3(numbers: values))

values = [-1,2,3,4]
print(findMaxMultiplicationOf3(numbers: values))

values = [1,-2,-3,-4]
print(findMaxMultiplicationOf3(numbers: values))

values = [-1,-2,-3,-4]
print(findMaxMultiplicationOf3(numbers: values))

values = [5, 10, 2, -100, -5]
print(findMaxMultiplicationOf3(numbers: values))

values = [5, 10, 2, -100, -15, -50]
print(findMaxMultiplicationOf3(numbers: values))

values = [-1,-2,-3,-4]
print(self.findMaxMultiplicationOf3(numbers: values))
```

Outputs: 120, 240, 24, 12, 12, 5000, 50000, -6

```
func findMaxMultiplicationOf3(numbers: [Int]) -> Int {
    var results: [Int] = []
    // Find the top 3 largest numbers
    let positive = numbers.filter({ $0 > 0 }).sorted(by: { $0 > $1 })
    let negative = numbers.filter({ $0 < 0 }).sorted(by: { $0 < $1 })

    func addPositiveAndNegativeNumbers() {
        // This adds one largest positive number and two largest negative numbers
        results.append(positive[0])
        add2LargestNegativeNumbers()
    }

    func add2LargestNegativeNumbers() {
        if negative.count >= 2 {
            var i: Int = 0
            while i < 2 {
                results.append(negative[i])
                i = i + 1
            }
        }
    }

    func add3LargestPositiveNumbers() {
        var i: Int = 0
        while i < 3 {
            results.append(positive[i])
            i = i + 1
        }
    }

    func multiplyToGetResult() -> Int {
        var i: Int = 0
        var result = 1
        while i < 3 {
            result = result * results[i]
            i = i + 1
        }
        return result
    }

    // Check if there are atleast 3 positive numbers
    if positive.count >= 3 {
        // 1. Are there atleast two negative numbers? If yes, is any one -ve number greater than the largest positive number?
        if negative.count >= 2, let largestNegativeNumber = negative.first, let largestPositiveNumber = positive.first,
            abs(largestNegativeNumber) > abs(largestPositiveNumber) {
            // Pick the largest negative number, and the second negative number and choose 1 positive number
            addPositiveAndNegativeNumbers()
        }
        else {
            add3LargestPositiveNumbers()
        }
    }
    else {
        // Add top positive number
        if positive.count > 0 {
            // Add 2 negative numbers, so that the result becomes positive
            // Make sure to check if there are atleast two negative numbers
            addPositiveAndNegativeNumbers()
        }
        else {
            // There are no positive numbers.
            // pick the least three negative numbers
            if negative.count >= 2 {
                var i: Int = negative.count - 1
                while i >= 0 {
                    results.append(negative[i])
                    i = i - 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return multiplyToGetResult()
}
```

Comment: Wow, it works flawlessly and so effective. Thank you so much! This help me understand the language even more

Comment: You are welcome. There's more that can be optimized in that code. All the best to you.

Comment: For `[5, 10, 2, -100, -5]` your algo gives the wrong answer.

Comment: Wrong for `[-1,-2,-3,-4]`.

Comment: @Jessy, for [-1,-2,-3,-4], it shows 12 as expected.

Comment: Why is that expected? You can't multiply any three of those and get 12.

Comment: The question is about finding the largest number by multiplying any 3 numbers. Note that minus multiplied by minus would result in plus.

Comment: And then for the third multiplication…?

Comment: You are right. After a long day, I guess I'm not thinking straight. Need to rest.

Answer (score 0):

```swift
extension Sequence where Element: Numeric & Comparable {
  /// The greatest product of any three elements.
  /// - This will either involve
  /// 1. the greatest 3 elements
  /// 2. the lowest 2, and the single greatest
  var maxProductOf3: (product: Element, factors: [Element])? {
    let sorted = self.sorted()

    guard sorted.count >= 3 else {
      return nil
    }

    let greatest = sorted.last!
    let (product, lesserFactors) =
      [ sorted.dropLast().suffix(2),
        sorted.prefix(2)
      ]
      .map { lesserFactors in
        ( product: lesserFactors.reduce(greatest, *),
          lesserFactors
        )
      }
      .max { $0.product }!
    return (product, lesserFactors + [greatest])
  }
}

public extension Sequence {
  func max<Comparable: Swift.Comparable>(
    _ getComparable: (Element) throws -> Comparable
  ) rethrows -> Element? {
    try self.max {
      try getComparable($0) < getComparable($1)
    }
  }
}
```